# Crystal Reports 2011 in Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, crystal-reports, delphi-xe2

I need to find any solution to integrate Crystal Reports (version 2011) in Delphi XE2..

Unfortunately I cannot find ANY hint using Google...

Has anyone a clue for me?

Regards
Fabian

Comment: I used their ActiveX component to hook up to CR X.  Perhaps it still exists?

Comment: I wasnt able to find it till now... Are there any Delphi Components..?

Comment: Well I read sth now in the SAP Forums about an .NET integration...

Answer (score 0):

After a Phonecall with SAP it's not possible to interate CR 2011 in Delphi using ActiveX... 1 Possibility is switching to .net..

CR XI is usable with ActiveX components...

Thats all I found =)